# How is iteration for collision checks in Clojure done with time n^2/2?

Tags: clojure, collision

**I am not interested in the detection collision.**

I am used to the method of having two counters in two for loops with java like so:

The first loop parses over all the objects and contains the second loop. Its counter is the index of the current object being checked against all other objects.

The second for loop parses over all unchecked objects. Its counter is the index of the unchecked object currently being checked against the object being looked at by the first loop.

Pseudo code:

```
for(i++)
  for(int j = i, j++)
   collides(objects[i], objects[j)
```

How is this implemented in Clojure?

I am very used to using commands like `map` that do not have a counter, and I am wondering if this approach actually needs a counter. If there is a way to do this without a counter that would be preferable.

I also want to make clear that I do not wish to implement with time `n^2`. Rather I want to have the time `n^2/2` method which checks only the unchecked objects for collision.

Comment: Note that in big O notation the `/2` is discarded so you are left with `O(N^2)`

Comment: Right, how would I emphasize that I care about that detail? Would I remove the O? Would I put just `n^2/2`?

Comment: It is hard to do that because the way you count how long things take is a bit variable to start with. Sometimes setting variables might take a different amount of time to say.. checking conditions. I think the way you've written it is best.

Comment: // , @JasonBasanese, does the order in which this iterates over the objects matter, as long as all are checked against each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same code via a for:

```
(for [i (range (count objs))
      j (range i (count objs))
      :when (collide? (nth objs i) (nth objs j))]
    ...do stuff...)
```

It would run faster if you use a `loop` but it probably wouldn't look as nice.

Comment: // , It does look nice. Still counters

Answer (score 1):

To select all the pairs that collide without using counters:

```
(defn select-pairs [collide? objects]
  (for [tail (iterate rest objects) :while (seq tail)
        :let [x (first tail)], y tail :when (collide? x y)]
    [x y]))
```

For example,

```
(select-pairs < (range 4))
;([0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [1 2] [1 3] [2 3])
```

- This will work on any sequence, even an endless one.
- `collide?` is just the name for the criterion that selects the pairs.

Comment: Good job doing this without a counter. I'll definitely try this out.